# Monitoring Status of Message Sent to RabbitMQ via Web-Stomp web-socket

Tags: rabbitmq, web-stomp

Using web-stomp with RabbitMQ and web-socket (SockJS not used), after sending a message to a queue, how can the consumer be notified by the broker or monitor that the sent message has been consumed?

I've experimented with subscribing to the queue which makes the client a consumer and the goal is not to receive the message for processing, but to know when a consumer elsewhere has picked up, acknowledged the message and is no longer in the queue.

Answer (score 0):

In retrospect, I really do believe I'm breaking the spirit of "send it and forget it" with this question's approach.

The better approach will be to subscribe to another queue that will receive the "finished processing" message that will be sent from the processor. The client can take the appropriate actions from there.